# Use time selector from Power BI as an argument in my SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I have a simple query like :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.id_organization)) AS Count
FROM dbo.paiement p
WHERE p.statut = 'AUTHORIZED'
      AND p.[date] > '2018-01-30'
```

I try to show this data on a PBI dashboard where I have a date range selector. I want the date to be fill with the begin and end date in two different areas so the calculation refresh on the fly. How can I link the `AND p.[date] > 'XXXX-XX-XX'` to this selector ?

EDIT

I just find out that I can do something like

```
Associations Actives = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('BDD - Paiement'[id_organization]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Dates'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Dates'[Date], MAX('Dates'[Date]), DESC)
    )
)
```

But I want to have a `BETWEEN BeginDate AND EndDate` corresponding the time slider

PS : How do you call this kind of query bellow ?

Comment: Even not sure I think it could help you it is by me - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-dates-and-date-table-in-power-bi/

Comment: @SurajKumar it not seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. But thanks !

Comment: Normally with PowerBI, you would not filter the SQL query on the dates you wanted from the date slicer.  Instead, you would retrieve all dates of interest, then allow the slicer to update your visuals.  Why do you want the slicer to connect to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.

1. Import all the data you might need and do the filtering within Power BI.
2. If there's too much data to import, you can create a DirectQuery. This will pass your slicer selections back to the server on the fly and automatically pull the bits it needs.

What you can't do is pass slicer selections to your Query Editor connection string.

Comment: Can you lead me more and the second approach ? This is what I first tried to do but with linking the date slicer with the data.

I was finally able to do it by importing the right table only (without some columns for the sake of speed) then add what they call a "quick calcul" (or something similar)

Comment: Not sure what to add. You don't apply any date filtering when you set up the DirectQuery. When you set the date slicer, it will query the database for only the selected dates. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about) may be useful to understand better.